# Backbone Collection Fetch - point to specific JSON property

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm on a project where I need to fetch some data from the server and make a Backbone Collection from it. The following code works as expected:

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
var collection = new Collection({});
collection.fetch({
    url: "http://localhost/api/somecollection",
    success: function(response) {
       // Do something here
    }    
})
```

And the result is something like this:

```
{
   foo: "lorem ipsum",
   bar: [{
       a: "a",
       b: "b",
       c: "c"
   }, {
       a: "a",
       b: "b",
       c: "c"
   }]
}
```

The "bar" property is what I want to turn into a bb collection. I actually do it by getting the response and instantiating a new Collection with its models:

```
success: function(response) {   
    var newCollection = new Collection(response.models[0].attributes.bar);
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is to avoid a new instance of the collection, only one should be enough. And I can't change the server response in order to return the array I need only.

The question: is there a way to supply a param to "fetch" so it can refer to the "bar" prop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override [`Colletion.parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) to customize how your collection handles your server responses :

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    parse: function (resp) {
        return resp.bar;
    }
});
var collection = new Collection();
collection.fetch({
    url: "http://localhost/api/somecollection"  
});
```